# Anchoring the Material Floating Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

layout_anchor is not functioning with the Material Action button. Is there any other proper way to anchor it to the layout. I went through the Fab Documentation [Material Design Floating Action Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/#using-fabs) But I couldn't find any proper way to anchor the Button.

The below code was working properly before, But It is not functioning with the SDK update. The layout_anchor attribute disappears the button, But can see the button is there with the margins of the UI in XML editor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SatActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_barsettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_log_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_light_logout"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the Gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with  It is not functioning with the SDK update?

Comment: Updated the build tool version from 28 to 29

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Material3` to `MaterialComponents` in themes.xml